# How is this javascript function called, and what pattern is it using?

Tags: javascript, closures

I came across this type function in an example code, and it looks widely used. But I cannot figure out how to call this, or infact, what pattern it represents.

```
 l = function (a1){
  someVar = {
    someFn: function(a2){
       console.log(a1);
       console.log(a2);
    }
  }
}
```

How would i go about executing someFn? Does this have something to do with closures?

UPDATE:

This is how the code is being used. As @joseph-the-dreamer guessed, it is being used as part of a module, where:

```
  App.module("Module", function(a1) {
      someVar = {
        someFn: function(a2){
           console.log(a1);
           console.log(a2);
        }
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 7):

From it's current state, you need to call `l` first to set `someVar` to access `someFn`. Otherwise, you can't access `someFn` at all.

But without any variable declaration of `someVar`, calling `l` will create an *implied global* `someVar`. Implied globals isn't a good practice. You should declare `someVar` somewhere, even if you mean it to be a global.

```
var someVar;

l = function (a1){
  someVar = {
    someFn: function(a2){
       console.log(a1);
       console.log(a2);
    }
  }
}

l(1);
someVar.someFn(2);

//1
//2
```

You can also [return `someVar` from calling `l`](http://jsfiddle.net/wnBCw/1/) to access `someVar`. Note that this time, `someVar` is a local variable in `l`.

```
var l = function (a1){
  var someVar = {
    someFn: function(a2){
      console.log(a1);
      console.log(a2);
    }
  }
  return someVar;
}

l(1).someFn(2);
```

As for pattern, I think what you have there is an incomplete form of the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). Usually, module pattern wraps things in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and returns an object as an interface to the module.

Comment: What if `someVar` is declared above `l`'s assignment?

Comment: is there any way to do this with out using global variables?

Comment: @pinkpanther [return `someVar` as a result of calling `l`](http://jsfiddle.net/wnBCw/1/).

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer the op also needs "what pattern it represents."

Comment: Thanks for the IIFE! Exactly what I needed. To be exact, this is from @derrick-bailey marionette implemetation.

Answer (score 1):

If `someVar` is not a variable in a scope outside of `l()`, then you **cannot** call `someFn()`, since `someFn()` is a private member function of `someVar`.

Otherwise, if you do have access to `someVar`, then you can call `someFn()` like this `someVar.someFn()`. **Note** that in this case, the `console.log(a1)` will behave strangely since `a1` is has been assigned only since the last time `l()` was called.

Comment: At its current state, without any `someVar` declaration, *calling `l`* would make a global `someVar`. You can still access it somehow.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - I do not think what you are saying is true. Try running the above code with `alert(typeof someVar);` after it. You get `undefined`.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - My bad ;) Forgot to run `l()` first :). Running `l()` is required for this implicit global declaration to be true.

Comment: `since a1 is not declared in any scope at that time.` That isn't true, it is in the closure scope due to the call to `l()`.

Comment: @Chad you are correct if `l()` has been called before.  I'll remove that piece - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are 2 types of variables: **global** and **local**.

```
//local
var foo = "foo";

//global
bar = "bar";
```

From what I see in your sample, `l` is a global variable that is used to store an anonymous function. Inside this function there is a global variable named `someVar` that stores an object that has a local variable named `someFn` that stores an anonymous function.

To execute `someFn`, you must do the following:

```
l("Foo");               //This does not output anything
someVar.someFn("Bar");  //This will output "Foo" and then "Bar"
```

When you call `l("Foo");`, you are creating the global variable `someVar`. This in turn means you can use `someVar` anywhere even outside of the scope of the anonymous function stored in `l`. You are using closures for the argument `a1`.

A global variable can be used anywhere and I humbly suggest to limit its usage as it will pollute the global scope which means that it is quite error prone.

An approach that does not use global variables would be better. Little example here:

```
"use strict";

var l = function(a1) { //constructor
  var _a1 = a1; //private variable
  this.someFn = function(a2) { //public method
     console.log(_a1);
     console.log(a2);
  };
};

var object1 = new l("Foo");
var object2 = new l("Foo");
object1.someFn(1); //outputs "Foo" and then 1
object2.someFn(2); //outputs "Foo" and then 2
```

Comment: the op also needs "what pattern it represents."